# How can I update or delete a record from the JSON output using Laravel and Predis

Tags: json, laravel, redis, predis

I started a few months ago with Laravel and I want to implement Redis.

How and what is the best way to update or delete 1 or more records from `$test`.

```
    $allarticles = Article::all();
    $client = Redis::connection();
    $client->set('articles', $allarticles->toJson() );
    $test = $client->set('articles');
```

Output:

```
    [{
        "id":1,"title":"xQeMKGefAW","content":"44cuxAqVDS@gmail.com","created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{
        "id":2,"title":"a5wpRVRBNZ","content":"SsH9U5kF32@gmail.com","created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{
        "id":3,"title":"QF5xhsMh7d","content":"8erXnIojAM@gmail.com","created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{
        "id":4,"title":"gQVbDNbcmD","content":"27feouH6vc@gmail.com","created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{
        "id":5,"title":"FsOnoABBTg","content":"2qNutidwKZ@gmail.com","created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{
        "id":6,"title":"89sS4UASJl","content":"cQku7DBKSB@gmail.com","created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{
        "id":7,"title":"gpT3hO43V1","content":"EhzyEylbgw@gmail.com","created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{
        "id":8,"title":"1DKvbBn7yV","content":"0cSAxi9if3@gmail.com","created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{
        "id":9,"title":"pRr2LgzezC","content":"Aam0uuWLlF@gmail.com","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}
```

Answer:

```
$allarticles = Article::all()->keyBy('id'); $client = Redis::connection();
$newarray = array(); 
foreach ( $allarticles->toArray() as $key => $value ){
    $newarray[$key] = json_encode($value); } $client->hmset('testtest', $newarray);
    $qwerty = $client->HGETALL('testtest'); 
    print_r($qwerty);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing the whole json as a string, store them in a hashmap using hmset command, id is the member and rest of the json is the value.

http://redis.io/commands#hash

To set the json:

```
hmset articles 1 {"title":"xQeMKGefAW","content":"44cuxAqVDS@gmail.com","created_at":null,"updated_at":null} 2 {"title":"xQeMKGefAW","content":"44cuxAqVDS@gmail.com","created_at":null,"updated_at":null} and so on
```

To retrieve the whole json:

```
hgetall articles
```

To update one or more values use **HMSET**

To delete one or more values use **HDEL**

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do i do that, do i have to make a loop?

Comment: You need to get a key Value pair for example a hashmap from your Json. That is up to your app logic then a single call of Hmset will do the job. Similarly hgetall and heel are single call.

Comment: I hope you can give me an example :)

Comment: I made the following:         $allarticles = Article::all()->keyBy('id');
        $client = Redis::connection();
        $newarray = array();
        foreach ( $allarticles->toArray() as $key => $value ){
            $newarray[$key] = json_encode($value);
        }
        $client->hmset('testtest', $newarray);
        $qwerty = $client->HGETALL('testtest');
        print_r($qwerty); Is that the correct way?